# Setting up proxy for spring kafka application

Tags: java, networking, apache-kafka, proxy

I am running kafka application behind a proxy. How to set the proxyHost and proxyPort for that.

I learnt that kafka uses binary protocol over tcp. I was wondering if there was some way to set proxy for binary protocol like we do for http -

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dhttp.proxyHost=example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=example.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 App.jar
```

I tried above and got TimeOutException.

Comment: What kind of proxy? Why can't you just set the bootstrap servers to the proxy address?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry if the question wasn't clear. Our application is running on linux box which can access internet only through proxy (eg. example.proxy.org : 80). Our application has to consume events from external kafka cluster. How can we configure our application to do that?

Comment: Open the firewall to allow traffic to the broker ports? Install Kafka REST Proxy? Clients need to talk directly to the brokers otherwise.